# App crash on startup on iOS9 via Delphi X Seattle

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

I have a project(s) developed in previous versions of Delphi, pre DX Seattle. 
My steps to deploy on DX.

1) Copied projects and opened in DX. Did all the necessary type casting for Listviews etc. Deployed to simulator - worked.

2) Deployed to iDevices - Did not work ( Loads Splash Screen then crashes immediately on startup )

3) Deleted project file and cleaned/deleted all other Delphi files. Then created a new project under DX and re-added project files and updated project settings.

4) Deployed to iDevices via AD Hoc - Worked

5) Deployed to App Store - They approved the apps, yet they still don't work on iOS 9  devices

6) Saw there was a hotfix update for PA server. Installed and followed instructions in ReadMe.txt

7) Deployed to simulator after reinstalling SDK's - does not work.

Anyone else having issues in DX and iOS 9? I have latest version of XCode installed as well. How can I run my apps in iOS 9 simulator and devices?

Comment: Note: in step 4) the Ad Hoc release worked on all versions of iOS including iOS 9. Not sure why the App Store release didn't work on iOS 9 versions. An even bigger question as to why Apple approved the app(s) if they didn't work on iOS 9 when specifically stated in update/change log for Apple: 'iOS 9 support'.....

Comment: At the moment I believe you should ask directly Embt about this.